# How can I enumerate all modules in a multi-module Gradle project, with file locations?

Tags: java, gradle

I really want to be able to enumerate the projects in my multi-module Gradle projects, ideally with relative filenames. 
I.e,

./gradlew list-projects

- :foo         ./foo
- :nested-foo  ./foo/nested
- :bar         ./bar

etc. 
So far, nothing has come of googling. 
Does anyone have an idea how to do this? 
Note that I do   **not**  need the dependencies.

Comment: Did you check the "Example: Multi-project tree - water & bluewhale projects" in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html  ?
the "allprojects" closure is essentially a loop on all projects.  You can then manipulate each project using the Project DSL (and get it's path) via https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:path

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`Project` interface](https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html), it contains all you need.

In particular:

- `getAllProjects()` to retrieve a `Set<Project>` including the root project or `getSubprojects()` to retrieve a set again without the root project
- `getProjectDir()` will give you the absolute path of that project
- and combined with `relativePath(Object path)` from the root project will allow you to relativize the path.

And the code for doing what you need should live in a custom task.

Answer (score 1):

I need something like this myself; here's a working code snippet which adds all subprojects whose path begins with ":client:" to the current project's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    getProject()
        .getRootProject()
        .getSubprojects()
        .findAll { it.getPath().startsWith(':client:') }
        .forEach { compile project (it.getPath()) }
}
```